# add div to the foreach loop?

Tags: php

```
<?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>
<div class="<?php print $field->class; ?>">
 <?php print $field->content; ?>
 </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

the loop's result is as the following,

```
   <div class="1">.....</div>
   <div class="2">.....</div>
   <div class="3">.....</div>
   <div class="4">.....</div>


   <div class="1">.....</div>
   <div class="2">.....</div>
   <div class="3">.....</div>
   <div class="4">.....</div>

   <div class="1">.....</div>
   <div class="2">.....</div>
   <div class="3">.....</div>
   <div class="4">.....</div>
```

i want to group the first `<div>` like this.

```
    <div class="group">
   <div class="1">.....</div>
   <div class="2">.....</div>
   <div class="3">.....</div>
   </div>
  <div class="4">.....</div>
```

how to make the foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `$field->class` variable always ranges from 1 to 4, you can do the following. Otherwise you need to use a manual counter.

```
<?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>
    <?php if ($field->class == 1) :?> <div class="group"> <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="<?php print $field->class; ?>">
      <?php print $field->content; ?>
    </div>
    <?php if ($field->class == 4) :?> </div> <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Custom Counter**

```
<?php $counter = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): $counter++;?>
    <?php if ($counter == 1) :?> <div class="group"> <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="<?php print $field->class; ?>">
      <?php print $field->content; ?>
    </div>
    <?php if ($counter == 4) : $counter = 1?> 
        </div> 
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: <?php endif; $counter = 1 ?>, why the code add the $counter = 1 ,thank you.

Comment: Sorry, that should be _inside_ the condition, not outside. Fixed. You should use this method only if your class name has a chance to differ.

Comment: i still don't know  why should add $counter = 1<?php if ($counter == 4) : $counter = 1?>  in this line

Comment: It basically resets the counter to 1 every time it hits 4. Since you want the DIVs grouped by 4.

Answer (score 2):

should be similar, just use `foreach` instead of `for`

```
<style>
    .group{
        background: red;
        margin-top: 10px;
        float: left;
        }
</style>
<?php $count=0; ?>
    <?php for($i=0; $i<= 20; $i++): ?>
    <?php if($count == 0): ?>
        <div class="group">
    <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $count++ ?>
        <div class="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></div>
    <?php if($count == 4): ?>
        <?php $count=0; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try (raw code)

```
<div class="group">
<?php $c=0; foreach ($fields as $id => $field) : ?>
<?php if($c%3==0) : ?> </div><div class="group"><?php endif; ?>
        <div class="<?php print $field->class; ?>">
           <?php print $field->content; ?>
       </div>
<?php $c++; endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: and how to add the closed </div>

Comment: That's because it doesn't actually close the group div. Please fix your answer

Comment: JohnP, the $fields is an associative array, if the $id is not a number. that $id%4==0 will be useless.

Comment: @zhuanzhou, then simple define `$c=0` and `$c++` inside `foreach`, update my answer